Nested sidemenu in flutter I got an error
Widget _buildMenuItem(BuildContext context, MenuItem item) {
    return ExpansionTile(
      title: Text(item.title),
      children: _buildSubMenu(context, item.children),
    );
  }

List<Widget>? _buildSubMenu(BuildContext context, List<MenuItem>? children) {
    if (children == null) {
      return null;
    }

    return children.map((child) {
      if (child.children != null) {
        return _buildMenuItem(context, child);
      } else {
        return ListTile(
          title: Text(child.title),
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.of(context).pop(); // Close the drawer
            if (child.routeName != null) {
              Navigator.pushNamed(context, child.routeName!);
            }
          },
        );
      }
    }).toList();
  }

This is the one page code of nested side menu in flutter every thing is working fine but I'm getting error here
The argument type 'List<Widget>?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<Widget>'.
I'm new bee in flutter please help if possible
Thank you...!

You are getting the error here:
children: _buildSubMenu(context, item.children),

The children property is of type
List<Widget> _buildSubMenu(BuildContext context, List<MenuItem>? children) {

which means it's not nullable, therefore you just need to change the return type of the method _buildSubMenu to List<Widget> and also you shouldn't return null in the _buildSubMenu:
List<Widget> _buildSubMenu(BuildContext context, List<MenuItem>? children) {
    return children.map((child) {
      if (child.children != null) {
        return _buildMenuItem(context, child);
      } else {
        return ListTile(
          title: Text(child.title),
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.of(context).pop(); // Close the drawer
            if (child.routeName != null) {
              Navigator.pushNamed(context, child.routeName!);
            }
          },
        );
      }
    }).toList();
  }

Check this link for more info:
https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety

what should I type in return value

just change the return type to List<Widget> instead of List<Widget>?

changed but getting error on return null : A value of type 'Null' can't be returned from the method '_buildSubMenu' because it has a return type of 'List'.

it's shows return children!.map is correct but I don't want to force
